# TrafficBot генератор на PHP

Tags: php

Дорогие друзья, может вопрос не в тему ) но всё же хочу спросить чисто ради интереса )) Как можно на PHP сделать "трафик бота", который эмулирует посетителя на сайт ? Какие данные надо посылать серверу чтоб тот посчитал их за пользователей ? или дайте ссылку где можно почитать об этом )

Comment: `.. данные надо посылать серверу чтоб тот посчитал их` узнать это можно только глянув на исходники бэкэнда самого сервера. кому-то хватит банального `curl http://foo.bar`, а кому-то надо и заголовки передать и эмулировать движения мышкой перед кликом

Comment: К сожалению curl не поддерживает имитацию пользователей

Comment: зависит от того, что вы подразумеваете под имитацией пользователя. ходить по сайту, кликать в ссылки, смотреть баннеры, отправлять события движения мышкой в метрику и т.п. - всё это он умеет. в сокет не умеет разве что